# How to check for purchased feature (InApp Purchase) when user delete and reinstall the app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am working on a project which include InApp purchase functionality. I am done with it and I store a key in `NSUserDefault` when user purchase the feature and check for the key to unlock the feature of app if user has already purchased it. But now the problem is that what if user delete the app and reinstall it, then all data of `NSUserDefault` get deleted. So what is the solution to check for unlocking the feature in that case??  Please tell me the possible solutions.

Thanks!!

Comment: you can use the Restore Inapp Purchase Option

Comment: You have to give the Restore Inapp Purchase Option otherwise your app will get rejected.

Comment: I have already restored the transaction but now the problem is how to check if user has already purchased the feature or not at launch time in order to unlock the feature??

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)RestoreBtnClicked:(id)sender
{

 [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]restoreCompletedTransactions];
}


// Then this is called

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    NSLog(@"%@",queue );

    NSLog(@"Restored Transactions are once again in Queue for purchasing %@",[queue transactions]);


    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"received restored transactions: %i", queue.transactions.count);

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:
    @"Purchase Restored" message:nil delegate:
        self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];


  for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {

        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;

        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];

        NSLog (@"product id is %@" , productID);

        // example if ([productID isEqualToString: @"youruniqueproductidentifier]){write files} else { nslog sorry}
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shangari..I have already restored the transaction but now the problem is how to check if user has already purchased the feature or not at launch time in order to unlock the feature??

Answer (score 0):

When you'll submit your app to the AppStore, most likely it will be rejected since your solution doesn't provide an ability to restore user's IAPs on different devices using the same Apple ID. You are responsible for adding this feature to app. It might happens automatically or on user's demand, based on your UI flow.

Before start to implement, read related [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)

After you check that user is already purchased a feature you may store it as you proposed to do using NSUserDefaults, that will give you an ability to save app state between launches.

That is a most common and frequently used approach.